# Mac OS X 10.5.7 Installing Wine with sudo and MacPorts

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Using a Macintosh with OS X 10.5.7. Unsure how to operate terminal, and trying to install Wine using Mac ports. Unfortunately the sudo command doesn't perform as expected.

> ```
> ******-imac:~ James$ sudo port install wine
> -bash: sudo: command not found
> ******-imac:~ James$
> ```

Question: how to install Wine in OS X using the sudo command in the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Does /usr/bin/sudo work?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with David M. Williams.  If sudo were found, the response you get would be different than what you're seeing.

The issue is *not* that "port" is not found.  Here's the error you get in that case (and I'm also using bash):

```
[02:04] Ailsie:data: $ sudo port install wine
sudo: port: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your `$PATH` variable?  This is the variable that tells your computer where to look for executables.  It's likely set incorrectly.  Please type the following into Terminal, hit Enter, and paste the results in:

`echo $PATH`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a PATH problem.

What is the output of "echo $PATH" in Terminal.app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you an admin or a normal user? This could possibly be the problem.